# AWS Cloudfront ERR_CACHE_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using AWS Cloudfront to service audio files to user. Recently several user reported that they are unable to play my audio file. A browser refresh is required to make it work if the audio is stuck.

In the Google Chrome console, it outputs

```
Failed to load resource: 
net::ERR_CACHE_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

I already have a cache settings in my Cloudfront Behavior settings,
Only default settings is on the origin s3 bucket.

[CF cache settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDJ7p.png)

Any suggestion?

Comment: The header `x-cache:Hit from cloudfront` is presented in the audio file get request

Comment: This isn't referring to the CloudFront cache, but rather the browser cache.  It seems to be related to seekable content, as in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543367 *et seq.*, but you should automatically have a strong validator (etag) if the origin is S3.  Can you capture request/response headers from before, during, and after the issue occurs?

Comment: It would also be helpful to review your CloudFront logs. If the users in question happen to be accessing the same CloudFront edge (which will show in the logs as an XXXN or XXXNN code) then you have an increased possibility that there is problematic behavior from CloudFront involved, e.g. bad content somehow stored in an edge cache -- unlikely, but worth ruling out, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with a cloudfront video failing to load due to this error. I was able to resolve it using javascript like this:

```
var videoLink = videoControl1.children[0].src; // videoControl1 is the HTML5 video element, should work similarly for audio.
if (!videoControl1.readyState){
    videoControl1.children[0].src = videoLink + "?v=" + Math.random();
    videoControl1.load();
}
```

I followed the suggestion from here: https://github.com/igvteam/igv.js/issues/424#issuecomment-336336788

Comment: that way it will never cache video.

Comment: Cache busting. Not a bad solution if the problem can't be resolved another way. However my specific issue doesn't exist in Cloudfront so this works for me. 

If your issue is in Cloudfront, be aware that cloudfront itself is a cache so one shouldn't bust the cache other than intentional invalidation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to change audio/video source dynamically and play that video/audio, you need to load with load() JS function first that resource before playing.